# HTC 816g octacore got stuck in the no command screen

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, updates, htc-desire

Yesterday an update came to my mobile. I updated and was installing the update an then an error occured. After that i restarted my mobile and from then on a no command screen is coming. My mobile is not rooted. Also in the downside it is showing No .zip file in internal storage.
Please help asap.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem "no command"  (*Resting Android robot*) screen.

I tried to do a factory reset using hardware buttons as mentioned [here](http://www.htc.com/in/support/htc-desire-816g-dual-sim/howto/552476.html).

I tried to enter *Boot mode* by pressing <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> button where it presents with *Recovery mode*, *Reboot system now*, *Apply update*.
I selected on *Reboot system now* using power button to see that my phone switched on without any issues.